# I don't see the mistake. (Conversion code for Mailto)

Tags: java, string, mailto, for-in-loop

My intentions is convert a String for mailto but, I found a problem, when I set breakline remove all and set only the last line.

```
public String mailto(String texto){
    String total="";

    for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++)
        if (texto.charAt(i)!=' ' && texto.charAt(i)!='\n'{
            total += texto.charAt(i);
        } else {
            if(texto.charAt(i)==' ') {
                total = total + "%20";
            } else {
                if(texto.charAt(i)=='\n'){
                    total = total + "%0D%0A";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return total
}
```

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd if statements should probably be checking against `== ' '` and `=='\n'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t hand-roll URL encoding (it’s quite easy to get wrong!), use the existing [`URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) for that.

```
public String mailto(String texto) {
    return URLEncoder.encode(texto);
}
```

Note that this yields a slightly different (but valid) result: space is encoded as `+` instead of as `%20`.

If for some reason you want/need to write your own ad-hoc email encoder, you can shorten your code by using [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
public String mailto(String texto) {
    return texto.replace(" ", "%20").replace("\n", "%0D%0A");
}
```

If you’re concerned about performance (be careful to actually measure!), don’t construct your string via concatenation, use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead.

Together with the fixes of your code, as well as a slight rewrite to increase readability, this yields

```
public String mailto(final String texto) {
    final StringBuillder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
        final char c = texto.charAt(i);
        if (c == ' ') {
            sb.append("%20");
        } else if (c == '\n') {
            sb.append("%0A%0D");
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: replace is better, but would a proper solution not be URL encoding using a library function?

Comment: @Clashsoft You’re totally right. I’m assuming that OP has some reason for hand-rolling it but who knows. Let me quickly add that.

Comment: I have the same problem with the replace, when i put \n only catch the last line

Comment: Apparently the problem, was the code "\n", i replace \n for System.lineSeparator() and this was all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public String mailto(String texto){
    String total="";

    for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++)
        if(texto.charAt(i)==' ') {
            total = total + "%20";
        } else if(texto.charAt(i)=='\n'){
            total = total + "%0D%0A";
        } else {
            total += texto.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return total
}
```

To reduce the number of tests you can inverse the logic: first check on `' '` and `'\n'`.